Error when Trying To Rebase Using Github Actions and github-script@v4
I am wanting to auto rebase using github actions but when I try to run my script I get an error:
Yml:
name: Auto Rebase Branch

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - dev
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - dev
    types: [opened, synchronize, reopened, closed]

permissions:
  contents: write
  pull-requests: write

concurrency:
  group: 'auto-rebase-${{ github.ref }}'
  cancel-in-progress: true

jobs:
  auto-rebase:
    runs-on:
      group: custom-runner-here
    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          fetch-depth: 0
          token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}

      - name: Rebase all open PRs
        uses: actions/github-script@v4
        with:
          github-token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
          script: |
            const baseBranch = 'dev';

            async function rebasePR(pr) {
              const headBranch = pr.head.ref;

              try {
                console.log(`Rebasing ${headBranch} on top of ${baseBranch}`);

                // Checkout the PR branch
                await exec.exec(`git checkout ${headBranch}`);

                // Perform the rebase operation
                await exec.exec(`git rebase ${baseBranch}`);

                // Force-push the rebased branch
                await exec.exec(`git push origin ${headBranch} --force`);

                console.log(`Successfully rebased ${headBranch} onto ${baseBranch}`);
              } catch (error) {
                console.error('Error during rebase:', error.message);
                core.setFailed(`Rebase of ${headBranch} failed. Please resolve conflicts manually.`);
              }
            }

            async function main() {
              // Get all open pull requests for the base branch
              let page = 1;
              let hasMore = true;

              while (hasMore) {
                const { data: pullRequests } = await github.pulls.list({
                  owner: context.repo.owner,
                  repo: context.repo.repo,
                  state: 'open',
                  base: baseBranch,
                  per_page: 100,
                  page: page
                });

                if (pullRequests.length === 0) {
                  hasMore = false;
                }

                for (const pr of pullRequests) {
                  await rebasePR(pr);
                }

                page++;
              }
            }

            main();


But I get this error:
Run actions/github-script@v4
(node:116) [DEP0005] DeprecationWarning: Buffer() is deprecated due to security and usability issues. Please use the Buffer.alloc(), Buffer.allocUnsafe(), or Buffer.from() methods instead.

(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
Rebasing test11 on top of dev

Error during rebase: Unable to locate executable file: git. Please verify either the file path exists or the file can be found within a directory specified by the PATH environment variable. Also check the file mode to verify the file is executable.
Error: Rebase of test11 failed. Please resolve conflicts manually.

Rebasing test5 on top of UA-1991-2nd-work-around
Error during rebase: Unable to locate executable file: git. Please verify either the file path exists or the file can be found within a directory specified by the PATH environment variable. Also check the file mode to verify the file is executable.
Error: Rebase of test5 failed. Please resolve conflicts manually.


I think it has to do with the exec.exec ? But I am not sure.
What I want to accomplish here is to be able to automatically rebase any open PR's against dev. B/c when one branch becomes stale due to another pr being merged into dev I don't want to have to manually click the update branch with rebase button in the GUI. I want this to be automated.
I have to use the custom runner. Not ubuntu-latest.
Any help is appreciated.

Your custom runner does not have ‘git’ installed. Just use
runs-on: ubuntu-latest


I have to use the custom runner.
I tried installing git manually with apt but it takes forever and ultimately times out.

Perhaps you have a network policy that blocks egress traffic to these domains: archive.ubuntu.com:443 and keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 and keyserver.ubuntu.com:11371
